# How do I tell if my application is running as a 32-bit or 64-bit application?

Tags: c#, 64-bit, 32-bit

How do I tell if my application (compiled in Visual Studio 2008 as *Any CPU*) is running as a 32-bit or 64-bit application?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
if (IntPtr.Size == 8) 
{
    // 64 bit machine
} 
else if (IntPtr.Size == 4) 
{
    // 32 bit machine
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the compiler play any role in between?

Comment: Just for those who are on .NET 4+ - there is a better answer now bellow about Environment.Is64BitProcess

Answer (score 165):

If you're using [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) 4.0, it's a one-liner for the current process:

```
Environment.Is64BitProcess
```

Reference: *[Environment.Is64BitProcess Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitprocess.aspx)*  (MSDN)

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer, that's great to know. I'm not going to change the current accepted answer because this question was originally about .NET 3.5 but I would encourage people to up vote your answer as well.

Answer (score 5):

I found this code from [Martijn Boven](http://bytes.com/forum/thread525905.html) that does the trick:

```
public static bool Is64BitMode() {
    return System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)) == 8;
}
```

Comment: It's likely more efficient to call IntPtr.Size instead of Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr))

Answer (score 5):

This code sample from Microsoft All-In-One Code Framework can answer your question:

[Detect the process running platform in C# (CSPlatformDetector)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSPlatformDetector-e7a99806)

> The CSPlatformDetector code sample demonstrates the following tasks
>   related  to platform detection:
>
> 1. Detect the name of the current operating system.    *(e.g. "Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise")*
> 2. Detect the version of the current operating system.   *(e.g. "Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7600.0")*
> 3. Determine whether the current operating system is a 64-bit operating    system.
> 4. Determine whether the current process is a 64-bit process.
> 5. Determine whether an arbitrary process running on the system is 64-bit.

If you just want to determine whether the currently running process is a 64-bit 
process, you can use the [Environment.Is64BitProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitprocess.aspx) property that is new in .NET 
Framework 4.

And if you want to detect whether an arbitrary application running on the system 
is a 64-bit process, you need to determine the OS bitness, and if it is 64-bit, 
call `IsWow64Process()` with the target process handle:

```
static bool Is64BitProcess(IntPtr hProcess)
{
    bool flag = false;

    if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
    {
        // On 64-bit OS, if a process is not running under Wow64 mode, 
        // the process must be a 64-bit process.
        flag = !(NativeMethods.IsWow64Process(hProcess, out flag) && flag);
    }

    return flag;
}
```

Comment: Can be a useful library, just a bit overkill in this context :).

Answer (score 1):

In .Net Standard you can use `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.OSArchitecture`

Comment: Also in .NET Framework since .NET Framework 4.7.1 (from 2017).