# How to determine 32 bit vs. 64 bit ASP.NET being used?

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET server that I do not have direct access to.  How can I write a .NET application that will programmatically determine whether ASP.NET is running 32 bit vs. 64 bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Already answered here:

[How do I tell if my application is running as a 32-bit or 64-bit application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266082/how-do-i-tell-if-my-application-is-running-as-a-32-or-64-bit-application)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to do this:

```
Int32 addressWidth = IntPtr.Size * 8;
```

since `IntPtr.Size` is 4 bytes on 32-bit architecture and 8 bytes on 64-bit architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724340%28VS.85%29.aspx)

This is a code sample found [here](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid495E7D0ED07BA35F5F0CE0EEFE87D7375BF1CF55.aspx).

```
private enum Platform
{
    X86,
    X64,
    Unknown
}

internal const ushort PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL = 0;
internal const ushort PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA64 = 6;
internal const ushort PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 = 9;
internal const ushort PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_UNKNOWN = 0xFFFF;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct SYSTEM_INFO
{
    public ushort wProcessorArchitecture;
    public ushort wReserved;
    public uint dwPageSize;
    public IntPtr lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
    public IntPtr lpMaximumApplicationAddress;
    public UIntPtr dwActiveProcessorMask;
    public uint dwNumberOfProcessors;
    public uint dwProcessorType;
    public uint dwAllocationGranularity;
    public ushort wProcessorLevel;
    public ushort wProcessorRevision;
};

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
internal static extern void GetNativeSystemInfo(ref SYSTEM_INFO lpSystemInfo);        

private static Platform GetPlatform()
{
    SYSTEM_INFO sysInfo = new SYSTEM_INFO();
    GetNativeSystemInfo(ref sysInfo);

    switch (sysInfo.wProcessorArchitecture)
    {
        case PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64:
            return Platform.X64;

        case PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL:
            return Platform.X86;

        default:
            return Platform.Unknown;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution if your .NET app is running with a forced x86 compile flag for other reasons, but you still need to determine if the host system is 64 bit.