# How can my program determine if it is running on 32-bit or 64-bit Windows?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, 32bit-64bit, operating-system

Here's my question. What is the best way to determine what bit architecture your app is running on?

What I am looking to do: On a 64 bit server I want my app to read 64 bit datasources (stored in reg key Software\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources) and if its 32 bit I want to read 32 bit datasources, (i.e. Read from Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources).

I might be missing the point, but I don't want to care what mode my app is running in. I simply want to know if the OS is 32 or 64 bit.

[System.Environment.OSVersion.Platform doesn't seem to be cutting it for me. Its returning Win32NT on my local xp machine and on a win2k8 64 bit server (even when all my projects are set to target 'any cpu')]

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266082/how-do-i-tell-if-my-application-is-running-as-a-32-or-64-bit-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to detect Windows 64 bit platform with .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net) might be helpful.

Comment: I used this thanks. Thanks everyone else for their help also.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't even worry about this, normally. The system automatically redirects registry queries to `Software\Wow6432Node` when running a 32-bit app on a 64-bit platform.

Comment: To make your app run as 32-bit regardless of the platform, change the exe platform to "x86 only". It will still run on x64 platforms and be automatically redirected to the Wow6432Node keys.

Answer (score 4):

Try the property `Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem`.  This is a new one added in .Net 4.0 specifically for the purpose of checking the type of the operating system.

Comment: Thanks but I should have mentioned I'm restricted to .net 2.0

Answer (score 4):

Simple, safe, framework version agnostic solution without going to the registry:

```
Console.WriteLine(
    "Is 64-bit? {0}",
    (
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)) == sizeof(Int64)
            ? "Yes" 
            : "No"
    )
);
```

Comment: Yes but if its running in 32 bit mode on a 64 bit machine the above would return false no?

Answer (score 2):

You should not read Wow6432Node directly. Use [RegistryView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryview(v=VS.100).aspx) to specify a 32-bit view when running as a 64-bit app.

Comment: Unfortunately `RegistryView` available only from .NET 4.0.